# why doesn't the Particle Effect work on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to show the particle effect on iPhone. 
The application is Universal app. I've already tested the app on iPad, so The particle effect work normally on iPad. but it doesn't appear on iPhone. there is no effect on the iPhone screen.

I couldn't find the reason why it doesn't work.

```
@interface MenuSceneController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
    EAGLView        *mParticle;
};

- (void)addParticle
{    
    mParticle = [[EAGLView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(335, 200, 1024, 768) andFileName:@"particle.pex"];    

    mParticle.alpha = 0.99;
    mParticle.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:mParticle];
    [mParticle startAnimation];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)_frame andFileName:(NSString *)_filename
{    
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:_frame]))
    {
        // Get the layer
        CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;

        eaglLayer.opaque = NO;
        eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], 
                                        kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, 
                                        kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, 
                                        kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, 
                                        nil];

        renderer = [[ES1Renderer alloc] initWithParticleFileName:_filename];

        if (!renderer)
        {
            [self release];
            return nil;
        }

        animating = FALSE;
        displayLinkSupported = TRUE;
        animationFrameInterval = 1;
        displayLink = nil;
        animationTimer = nil;

        NSString *reqSysVer = @"3.1";
        NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
        if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
            displayLinkSupported = TRUE;
    }
    return self;
}
```

"particle.pex" file is the particle effect file.

Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's because you didn't adjust your screen size to that of an iPhone?

```
CGRectMake(335, 200, 1024, 768)
```

Comment: thanks, so i adjust the screen size for iPhone. but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, LearnCocos2D, What do you think of .pex file?